# android, set spinner value to default after clicking save

Tags: android, spinner

So i have this method to save some values to sharedpref. I am also storing 3 spinner. I have problems with spinner 3. Actualy has onclick listener. For example if you click 3 you get a popup window with androids "setTimePicker". This works well, but now i need to set the value in spinner to 0 when either the user selects all 3 clocks, either he cancels all 3 clock or when he clicks save. 
How could i achive that?. Adding a picture to understand better.

Main page:

[image]

Time selector:

[image]

After you select time: (the spinner should now be like in main page ! no value!)

[image]

```
   public void shrani_nastavitve(){

        shrani_nastavitve.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        String bolecina_main = spinner_pain.getSelectedItem().toString();;
                        String zdravilo_main = spinner_medicine.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        String kolicina_main = spinner_dailyInput.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        String ura1_main = clock1.toString();
                        String ura2_main = clock2.toString();
                        String ura3_main = clock3.toString();

                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("nastavitve_uporabnika", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                        if (bolecina_main.equals("")) {
                        } else {
                            editor.putString("bolecina", bolecina_main);
                        }
                        if (zdravilo_main.equals("")) {
                        } else {
                            editor.putString("zdravilo", zdravilo_main);
                        }
                        if (kolicina_main.equals("")) {
                        } else {
                            editor.putString("dnevna_kolicina", kolicina_main);
                        }
                        if (ura1_main.equals("")) {
                        } else {
                            editor.putString("ura1", ura1_main);
                        }
                        if (ura2_main.equals("")) {
                        } else {
                            editor.putString("ura2", ura2_main);
                        }
                        if (ura3_main.equals("")) {
                        } else {
                            editor.putString("ura3", ura3_main);
                        }
                        editor.apply();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Uspešno shranjeno!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

    }
```

Spinner values

```
 <string-array name="spinner_myDailyMedicineInput">
        <item></item>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
        <item>6</item>
        <item>7</item>
        <item>8</item>
    </string-array>



 spinner_dailyInput.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position){

                    case 1:
                        for(int i=0;i<1;i++) {
                            clock2=null;
                            clock3=null;
                            clock4=null;
                            clock5=null;
                            clock6=null;
                            clock7=null;
                            clock8=null;
                            setTimePicker(i);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
                            clock3=null;
                            clock4=null;
                            clock5=null;
                            clock6=null;
                            clock7=null;
                            clock8=null;
                            setTimePicker(i);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
                            clock4=null;
                            clock5=null;
                            clock6=null;
                            clock7=null;
                            clock8=null;
                            setTimePicker(i);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
                            clock5=null;
                            clock6=null;
                            clock7=null;
                            clock8=null;
                            setTimePicker(i);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
                            clock6=null;
                            clock7=null;
                            clock8=null;
                            setTimePicker(i);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
                            clock7=null;
                            clock8=null;
                            setTimePicker(i);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
                            clock8=null;
                            setTimePicker(i);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {
                            setTimePicker(i);
                        }

                        break;
                    default:
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the solution, removed some code and placed clear the spinners after the save is initialized.

```
 shrani_nastavitve.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (spinner_pain == null)
                        {
                            bolecina_main="";
                        }
                        else  {
                            bolecina_main = spinner_pain.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        }
                        if (spinner_medicine== null){
                            zdravilo_main="";
                        }
                        else {
                            zdravilo_main = spinner_medicine.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        }
                        if (spinner_dailyInput==null){
                            kolicina_main="";
                        }
                        else {
                            kolicina_main = spinner_dailyInput.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        }
                        if(clock1==null){
                            ura1_main="";
                        }
                        else {
                            ura1_main = clock1.toString();
                        }
                        if(clock2==null){
                            ura2_main="";
                        }
                        else {
                            ura2_main = clock2.toString();
                        }
                        if(clock3==null){
                            ura3_main="";
                        }
                        else {
                            ura3_main = clock3.toString();
                        }

                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("nastavitve_uporabnika", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                        if (bolecina_main.equals("")) {
                        } else {
                            editor.putString("bolecina", bolecina_main);
                        }
                        if (zdravilo_main.equals("")) {
                        } else {
                            editor.putString("zdravilo", zdravilo_main);
                        }
                        if (kolicina_main.equals("")) {
                        } else {
                            editor.putString("dnevna_kolicina", kolicina_main);
                        }
                        if (ura1_main.equals("")) {
                        } else {
                            editor.putString("ura1", ura1_main);
                        }
                        if (ura2_main.equals("")) {
                        } else {
                            editor.putString("ura2", ura2_main);
                        }
                        if (ura3_main.equals("")) {
                        } else {
                            editor.putString("ura3", ura3_main);
                        }
                        editor.apply();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Uspešno shranjeno!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        spinner_dailyInput.setAdapter(null);
                        spinner_pain.setAdapter(null);
                        spinner_medicine.setAdapter(null);
                    }


                });
```